# Erro Umake Android

Tags: android-studio, linux

Estou com um problema, instalei pacote por pacote, mas quando fui usar o *"umake android"* ou *"Sudo umake android"*, ele retorna estes erros, procurei no google, mas ainda não encontrei a solução do problema.

print do erro:

http://prnt.sc/byoy2s
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Não copiei o erro, pois haviam muitos links e não tenho pontuação suficiente para publicá-los.

Sou novato em linux, então estou tendo vários problemas, mas este foi um dos que eu não consegui resolver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me informaram que este erro acontece quando o servidor nega o acesso de alguma forma.

Para resolver isso eu ao invés de instalar por linha de comando eu baixei o arquivo no site oficial e instalei de acordo com as especificações. Depois tive apenas que arrumar as variáveis locais...